# Finding the square of a number in a sequential array of odds

Tags: arrays, optimization

I have a sequential odd array starting at 3. So x = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13...}.
I am wondering if there is a quick way to find at what index the square of a number n is at. So if n was 5, I am looking for where 25 is in the array. Right now I have ((n) * (n - 1)) which I add to the current i index. Is there anything faster?

Comment: Use binary search algorithm,O(log n) complexity

Comment: that array isn't an array of odds, it just starts with an odd number, anyway is the array always built from consecutive numbers ? if not is it always sorted ?

Comment: @niceman it is always built from consecutive numbers and it always sorted in increasing order

Answer (score 0):

Your array is made of consecutive numbers and it's sorted, Because of this it forms a mathematical arithmetic progression with difference 1 and first element as 3, so at index `i` we have `a[i]=i+3` and so `i=a[i]-3`.

So to find the index of the square of `n` let `nsqr` be `n*n`, nsqr index is simply `nsqr-3`, that's an `O(1)` algorithm.

To make it general whenever we have consecutive sorted numbers which start with `a0` and differ by `d`, to find where is the square of `n` we do `(nsqr-a0)/d`.